# Save output, wavefunction file and orbital information in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, vqe, optimization, chemistry

I am going through LiH ground state energy calculation. I would like to know how to save the output file in Qiskit as one would do in classical computing using software like Gaussian or Psi4.

Can someone please help?